# SQL agent jobs appear as job id only

Tags: sql-server-2005

SQL Server 2005, I'm seeing about 100 'jobs' in the SQL Agent>jobs node in SSMS. They appear as hexadecimal strings not with their real names:

If I query msdb..sysjobs, I see a much smaller list of jobs and their corresponding JobName.

So what are these jobs and how can I make them appear as their real job name as opposed to the JobID?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Do you use subscriptions in reporting services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SQL Server 2005, I'm seeing about 100 'jobs' in the SQL Agent>jobs node in SSMS. They appear as hexadecimal strings not with their real names:

They are from reporting service subscriptions.

Below SQL will give you list of the job names against the actual reports

```
select ScheduleID
    ,Path
    ,name
    ,s.Description
from ReportServer.dbo.catalog c
inner join ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions s on c.ItemID = s.Report_OID
inner join ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule rs on rs.SubscriptionID = s.SubscriptionID
```

Even better ([got it from this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/deanka/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-subscriptions)):

> A SQL Server Agent job is created to control the scheduled execution of the report, and this is stored in the sysjobs and sysjobsteps of the MSDB database. **The agent job name is a guid value that represents the ScheduleId** (yes, in case you've not yet noticed, this makes your Agent Job list messy with a bunch of guids that make it hard to work with your non-subscription jobs, we are hearing you:).

```
select 'Report' = c.Path
    ,'Subscription' = s.Description
    ,'SubscriptionOwner' = uo.UserName
    ,'SubscriptionModBy' = um.UserName
    ,'SubscriptionModDate' = s.ModifiedDate
    ,'ProcessStart' = dateadd(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, Getutcdate(), Getdate()), n.ProcessStart)
    ,'NotificationEntered' = dateadd(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, Getutcdate(), Getdate()), n.NotificationEntered)
    ,'ProcessAfter' = dateadd(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, Getutcdate(), Getdate()), n.ProcessAfter)
    ,n.Attempt
    ,'SubscriptionLastRunTime' = dateadd(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, Getutcdate(), Getdate()), n.SubscriptionLastRunTime)
    ,n.IsDataDriven
    ,'ProcessHeartbeat' = dateadd(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, Getutcdate(), Getdate()), n.ProcessHeartbeat)
    ,n.Version
    ,n.SubscriptionID
from Notifications n
inner join Subscriptions s on n.SubscriptionID = s.SubscriptionID
inner join catalog c on c.ItemID = n.ReportID
inner join Users uo on uo.UserID = s.OwnerID
inner join Users um on um.UserID = s.ModifiedByID
```

Answer (score 1):

That hexadecimal job name must have come from job_id column which is present in both msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory table and msdb.dbo.sysjobs table. What does below query returns for the hex job ID

```
select sj.name,
sj.description,
sjh.step_name
from 
dbo.sysjobhistory sjh
join
dbo.sysjobs sj
on 
sj.job_id=sjh.job_id
where sjh.job_id=''--hex value
```

Comment: Hi Shanky, Interestingly, that query returns nothing when I use the hex id of any of the jobs listed in the SQL Agent jobs node. If I use any of the hex ids from the sysjobs dmv I also return no results.

Comment: Can you give more information about these Hex jobs schedule, owner properties this would help in drilling down issue

Comment: Looks like SSRS subscriptions: This job is owned by a report server process. Modifying this job could result in database incompatibilities. Use Report Manager or Management Studio to update this job.

Comment: owned by NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Comment: Ok so anyone got any ideas? Is this a bug or something I can resolve?

Comment: @user41868 Even though too late to the party, please see my answer. Thanks.